# IF statements to rank different ranges with field calculator in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.6

I have a simple calculation to perform using the Python Parser in ArcMap but am running into some trouble when it comes to coding the ranges of values.

I have three different fields: mean temperature, altitude, and precipitation that I would like to reclass. For example,

`if temperature is >= 18 and altitude <650 and precipitation >= 1200 then write Optimal`

`if temperature is < 12 and altitude >=1300 and precipitation is <900 then write Unsuitable`

`if mean temperature is between 12-17 and altitude is between 650-1299 and precipitation between 900-1199 then write sub-suitable`.

I get stuck at the last class when trying to do the code for calling up within a ranges of values. Finally, I have added a new field for the classes called MC_Clim.

This is the code I have come up with so far:

```py
def Reclass(temperature,altitude,precipitation):
       if tmean>= 18 and altitude< 650 and prec13>= 1200:
          val= "Optimal"
       elif tmean < 12 and altitude >= 1300 and prec13< 900:
          val= "Unsuitable"
      

Expression:
     Reclass (!temperature!,!altitude!,!precipitation!)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. I believe you just need to `return` your desired text string. And make sure argument names match your variable names (if mean temperature and temperature are different columns, be sure to include them as separate arguments)

```py
def Reclass(temperature,  altitude, precipitation):
   if temperature >= 18 and altitude < 650 and precipitation >= 1200:
      return "Optimal"
   elif temperature < 12 and altitude >= 1300 and precipitation < 900:
      return "Unsuitable"
   # to test if a value is inside a range
   elif 12 < temperature < 17 and 650 < altitude < 1299:
      return "Sub-suitable"
   return "N/A"    


## here you include column names as arguments 
Expression:
     Reclass (!tmean!,!altitude!,!prec13!)
```

[image]

Comment: you may want to use `<=` instead of `<` for the "Sub-suitable" range. It depends if 12 and 17 should be included in the target range.

Comment: Hi I have tried the code and it returns the error fail to execute:                                       def Reclass(tmean,  altitude, prec13):
   if tmean >= 18 and altitude< 650 and prec13>= 1200:
      return "Optimal"
   elif tmean < 12 and altitude >= 1300 and prec13< 900:
      return "Unsuitable"
   elif 12 <= tmean <= 17 and 650 <= altitude <= 1299 and 900 <= prec13 <= 1199:
      return "Sub-suitable"

Comment: I have enclosed my arguments in the Expression box as: Reclass (!tmean!, !altitude!,!precipitation!), however the error still comes up

Comment: is your precipitation column called `precipitation`? I have a feeling it is called `prec13`. So `Reclass (!tmean!, !altitude!,!prec13!)`   <-- these should be the field names in the attribute table

Comment: Hi, it works now. Apologies, error on my path. I had forgot to include the last line of code, return "N/A"...many thanks for all your help!